# Reduce a flux to mono using data from flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this scenario. I have one paginated API which gives me the data for last 12 months. The response of the API is like:

```
public class PagedTransfersDto {

  private List<Transfer> content;

  private Page page;

  @Getter
  public static class Transfer {
      private String id;
      private Long transferId;
      private Long transferRequestId;
      private String status;
      private BigDecimal accountReceivable;
      private BigDecimal accountPayable;
      private BigDecimal netReceivable;
      private BigDecimal netPayable;
      private String currency;
      private Long transferDate;
  }

  @Getter
  public static class Page {
      private Integer size;
      private Integer number;
      private Integer totalElements;
      private Integer totalPages;
  }
}
```

Now I have to collect all the data and then calculate the sum of all the `netReceivable` and return as a `Mono<CompanyIncome>`. This pojo is like

```
public class CompanyIncome {
  private BigDecimal inferredIncome = new BigDecimal(0);
}
```

To do this I have written something like:

```
CompanyIncome initialIncome = new CompanyIncome();
    return myService.getTransfers(0, 50, fromDate, toDate)
        .expand(pagedTransfersDto -> {
            if (pagedTransfersDto.getPage().getNumber().equals(pagedTransfersDto.getPage().getTotalPages())) {
                return Mono.empty();
            }
            return myService.getTransfers(pagedTransfersDto.getPage().getNumber() + 1, 50, fromDate, toDate);
        })
        .flatMap(pagedTransfersDto -> Flux.fromIterable(pagedTransfersDto.getContent()))
        .reduce(initialIncome, ((companyIncome, transfer) -> {
            companyIncome.setInferredIncome(companyIncome.getInferredIncome().add(transfer.getNetReceivable()));
            return companyIncome;
        }));
```

Now the catch is that it is possible that this data is only for 3 months in which case I have to extrapolate this to 12 months by multiplying by 4.

What I am thinking is to get the first item of transfers list and the last one and the see if the data is not for a whole year but cant think of a place where to perform this operation.

Since after reduce the transfers data is gone. Before that I cannot seem to find a way how to get this info and still reduce from transfers flux

I am a little new to reactive way and cant seem to find a way to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: only thing i can think of right now is keep 2 final AtomicLong variables outside (next to the initialIncome line) and every invocation of the "reduce" compare companyIncome.getTransferDate() against the 2 Longs to find the Min and Max transfer date. once the entire chain is finished, you will have the date range of all the transfers you retrieved.

Comment: Hi Tom thanks for this! These items should be sorted in my opinion so I need to get the first item and last item typically. So min will be last and max will be first. Now can I make use of this info somehow?

Comment: There are a few ideas. 1. You can reduce in reverse order if the items are sorted. Using that info you can change your initial state so that reduce keeps on working(not good if your stream is too big).  Or You can reduce it to a tuple. The first element has the value, and the second is the last processed element. Map after reduce should know if the last element was according to your criterion.

Comment: using variables external to the reactive chain is a code smell, as it introduces leaky shared state: if two subscriptions are made to the same `Mono`, they'll work on the same `CompanyIncome` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose, the best solution is to store the necessary "metadata" in the reduced object. You already have a `CompanyIncome` object, so maybe that is a good place? Otherwise I'd introduce either a `Tuple2` or some intermediate business object (eg. `CompanyIncomeAggregator`) into which to store both the aggregated income and the information that you need to decide at the end if further processing is necessary.

Then in a `map` step, you'd read that information, act on it and either return the computed income as is or modified according to your criterion.

Important note: Using variables external to the reactive chain is a code smell, as it introduces leaky shared state: if two subscriptions are made to the same Mono, they'll work on the same `CompanyIncome` object. You can remediate here by using `reduceWith`, which takes a `Supplier` for the initial value: `reduceWith(CompanyIncome::new, ...)`.